# Comunicação TEF

Tags: php, javascript, angularjs, laravel, zend-framework-2

Preciso integrar o TEF no meu sistema. Alguém faz ideia de como posso começar isto? Existe algum software de código aberto para fazer esta integração?
Encontrei umas informações na internet que falava sobre a **PayGo**, esta seria uma opção viável?

Meu sistema é Web, uso AngularJS e meu BackEnd em PHP, tenho um módulo de Vendas/Frente de loja.

Comment: Não é necessário desenvolver uma classe JS para comunicação com o PayGo.
A [NTK Solutions](http://www.ntk.com.br) disponibiliza uma API para TEF, POS e e-commerce. Chama-se ControlPay.
Com essa API você pode acionar o TEF diretamente da sua aplicação, via web service.
Quando a transação termina no PDV você recebe um callback na URL de retorno cadastrada no ControlPay.

Answer (score 2):

Faça o cadastro na PayGo e baixe a documentação com o roteiro de testes, documentação e o Gerenciador Padrão para testes. Resumindo: a implementação do TEF consiste basicamente na troca de arquivos com o Gerenciador Padrão (A documentação da PayGo explica como funciona). Você precisará desenvolver uma classe em Javascript para se comunicar com o GP. Você pode pesquisar por classes desenvolvidas em JAVA e converte-las para Javascript (Foi o que eu fiz). 
Você precisará desenvolver ou ter uma versão do seu Frente de Loja em desktop desenvolvido em NodeJS para criar os respectivos arquivos nas pastas do Gerenciador Padrão. Recomendo que vc utilize o Electron para desenvolver a versão desktop. https://electron.atom.io/